# I was making a new migration to create an association between two entities in ROR. I use the wrong entity in the migration and need to delete it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I was making a new migration to create an association between two entities in ROR. I use the wrong entity in the migration and need to delete it. How to delete the pending migration?

I did `bin/rails db:rollback` , and now it's saying migration pending.

````
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

You have 2 pending migrations:

20210308064215_devise_create_admins.rb
20210309031327_add_user_to_listing.rb

): ```
````

Comment: It depends if your migrations have been pushed to production. If you have migrated locally and rolled back, just ensure the database look good, and delete the two migrations files. If you have pushed the migrations to production, then I prefer to generate new migrations that reverse the previous migrations. It allows not to connect to the production console to roll back directly the production database.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.
If you've not run the migrations then you can do the following steps:

1. Delete the migrations manually.
2. Run the following command: `rake db:migrate:down VERSION="20210308064215" AND rake db:migrate:down VERSION="20210309031327"`
3. Run the following command: `rails d migration devise_create_admins` AND `rails d migration add_user_to_listing`

Just let me know if that works for you.